# Identify piano soundtrack in "Capitulo" soap opera

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I have a piano tune that I need identified. It is from a Spanish soap opera *Capitulo* (episode 64) and I can’t figure out if it is *Claire de Lune* or not!

The link for the YouTube video is [here](https://youtu.be/WLHef6kysZM?t=626), it starts in 10:20 and ends at 10:45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a piano improvisation around the traditional song *Besame Mucho*.

Here is a recording by "el padre", [Julio Iglesias](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4sSM5lXPOc).

Comment: Yes!!!! It is that!! Thanks so much! No wonder I felt I knew it, it just sounds different without the Jazz!!